# Need help naming a fractal/image generated by exponential

Tags: logarithms, computer-science, fractals

[image]

I'm taking an introductory comp-sci course this semester, and my professor pulled up this graphic while explaining mergesort (the graphic shows blocks of size $2^{-n}$). For some reason, the vertical lines that appear in this photo look familiar to me, but I can't seem to find anything online or put my finger on it. Is there a name for a fractal that's generated in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the position
of the first nonzero bit
when counting in binary.

An expression might be
$v_2(n)$
where $v_m(n)$
is the largest power of $m$
that divides $n$.

This can be expressed in
a few ways.

$m^{v_m(n)} | n$,
$m^{v_m(n)+1} \not\mid n$.

Algorithmically,

$v_m(n)=
\begin{cases} m | n &: 1+v_m(n/m)\\
 \text{else}&: 0\\
\end{cases}
$

Comment: Then shouldn't the height of the fourth bar be $3$ and not $4$?

Comment: There may be a constant that everything is off by.

Answer (score 0):

It bears a small resemblance to both the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) and the [Blancmange curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve), mainly because those are both fractals that are depicted as heights above (or below) an interval that gets split in some way.